# Как находить площадь фигуры, ограниченной линиями?

Tags: c#, математика, интегральное-исчисление

Появилась задача "написать программу нахождение площади фигуры, ограниченной линиями", хотя бы для простейшего базового случая "площадь плоской фигуры, ограниченной линиями `y=2x - x**2, y = -x`".

Понятно, что площадь фигуры это интеграл. Рекомендуется сначала нарисовать график т.к. много частных сложных случаев. Также ещё  есть метод Симпсона примерно на эту же тему.

Стал смотреть как это применить, и понял что на `c#` класс `System.Math` вообще не содержит ничего про интегральные вычисления. В `python`, видимо, то же самое. Есть реализация метода Симпсона, но это не вполне то что надо.

Что тут можно сделать?

Comment: Если функции такие простые, то решить аналитически :) Если посложнее (не берется аналитически), то Симпсон — вполне нормальное решение...

Comment: В общем случае эта задача не решается. У вас могут оказаться расходящиеся интегралы (например, `y=1/x` и `y=x`) или неограниченные фигуры (`y=sin(x)` и `y=0`). Нужно накладывать какие-то ограничения. Скажем, функции `f1` и `f2` непрерывны, интервал интегрирования конечен. Тогда первый шаг - найти все точки в которых `f1(x) = f2(x)`. Затем установить все интервалы "между линиями" в пределах интервала интегрирований. Ну и потом проинтегрировать по найденным интервалам `\integral |f1-f2|dx`. Метод симпсона вполне себе подходящий.

Comment: Не скажу за C#, а в `python` есть [`scipy.integrate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/integrate.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проиллюстрирую на Питоне, на нём проще рисовать. Если я правильно посчитал площади. Сначала чисто визуально ищем точки пересечения (хотя лучше аналитически). Потом бьём фигуру на трапеции и считаем их площади. Чем больше трапеций - тем точнее вычисления. В итоге они сходятся к какой-то цифре. Данный код сделан в основном для визуальной иллюстрации.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def calc_x_y(delta=None, points=None):
    if points:
        x = np.linspace(-0, 3, points)
    else:
        x = np.arange(0, 3 + delta, delta)
    y1 = 2 * x - x**2
    y2 = -x
    return x, y1, y2

def calc_s_and_plot(delta, plot):
    plt.figure();
    x, y1, y2 = calc_x_y(points=100)
    plt.plot(x, y1, c='g');
    plt.plot(x, y2, c='b');

    x, y1, y2 = calc_x_y(delta=delta)
    s = 0
    for i in range(x.shape[0] - 1):
        if plot:
            plt.plot([x[i], x[i]], [y1[i], y2[i]], c='r', linestyle='--')
            plt.fill_between([x[i], x[i+1]], [y1[i],y1[i+1]], [y2[i],y2[i+1]], color='cyan', alpha=0.5)
        xx = (x[i] - x[i+1]) / 2
        yy1 = (y1[i] + y1[i+1]) / 2
        yy2 = (y2[i] + y2[i+1]) / 2
        #plt.plot([xx, xx], [yy1, yy2], c='c', linestyle=':')
        s += -(yy1 - yy2) * xx
    if not plot:
        plt.fill_between(x, y1, y2, color='cyan', alpha=0.5)
    plt.title(f'Шаг: {delta}, Площадь: {s:.4f}')

# оценка "на глаз": примерно четверть квадрата [0,3]x[-3,1], т.е. 12/4 = 3
delta = 1

calc_s_and_plot(1, True)
calc_s_and_plot(0.1, True)
calc_s_and_plot(0.00001, False)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Если задача решается для двух функций, которые пересекаются лишь в двух точках, то необходимо определить точки пересечения данных функций с координатами (х1, у1) и (х2,у2). Разбить с определенным шагом интервал х2-х1 (чем меньше шаг, тем точнее интегрирование). пусть шаг по оси абсцисс х_шаг. Начиная от х1 определяем f1(x1) и определяем f1(x1+x_шаг). А теперь мы определяем площадь участка между х1 и x1+x_шаг по формуле: `S_1=1/2*x_шаг*(f1(x1) + f1(x1+x_шаг))` - (в общем случае это прямоугольная трапеция). Все это суммируется для одной функции f1, потом для f2. И далее вычитаете из одной площади - другую: S_f1 - S_f2. Вот собственно и всё.

Comment: Было бы полезно упомянуть недостатки данного способа, и примерную оценку точности в зависимости от шага